# Generic type defined as subclass + interface

Tags: java, generics, interface

I need to defined a Generic type as a subclass implementing an interface, like this (DOES NOT COMPILE):

```
public class Foo<T extends SomeClass implements SomeInterface> {
    ...
}
```

Is it possible to do something like this?

Jon Skeet, where are you when we need you ;)

Comment: i think jon will be sleeping now. he was sighted today 7:45 IST and thats 2:15 GMT. guess he is not at london. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's the syntax:

```
public class Foo<T extends SomeClass & SomeInterface> {
}
```

These are called [Intersection Types](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#108433). They don't differentiate between classes and interfaces. Intersection types are also briefly mentioned in the [Java tutorial on Bounded Type Parameters](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html).